# Can't login to Joomla(3.4) back end or front end it keeps refreshing

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I build a site with Joomla 3.4 and all was fine. I think the authentication Joomla plugin was disabled accidentally. I tried everything to fix it in phpmyadmin jos-plugin table.

I published the authentication-joomla ,user-joomla, com-user and all related but it isn't working.

Comment: Did you disable the "Remember Me" plugin before the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

Strangely had the same issue with a client site once.

I tried removing the `.htaccess` file and replacing all core files with a fresh copy of Joomla, but still didn't work.

In the end, I found that there appeared to be a problem with the `configuration.php` file. All the variables were in a jumbled order and there were values set that shouldn't have been.

I ended up replacing it with a fresh copy of the file and changing the main variables such as database details, log/tmp directories and secret.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't give a lot of information, like if you tried to move the website from server to server, or if you are getting any messages.

If you have made sure that the required plugins are enabled, then I would suggest you to review your configuration file.

In the configuration check if the following variables have any values.

```
public $cookie_domain
public $cookie_path
public $live_site
```

If yes, remove the values like so:

```
public $cookie_domain = '';
```

Then see if you can login.

Comment: i have not moved the website and i am not getting any message when i try to login the page just refreshes itself the configurations you mentioned are  all empty still i cant login

Answer (score 1):

Many times this can be due to the Joomla Authentication plugin being disabled.  To fix it you can log in to your PHPMyAdmin from your cpanel or other hosting control panel then you want to locate the #_extensions table where you'll find the field for the plg_joomla_authentication.  Set the the value to 1.